# What's the purpose of the Linux filesystem checkers' "interactive mode"?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fsck, interactive

Linux's [`fsck`](http://enwp.org/fsck) disk-repair tool often runs in an "interactive mode" by default. This means that, if it finds problems, it may ask me questions. But these questions tend to assume that I am a filesystem expert. In practice, I generally have no idea what I should answer to any of the questions.

Why would anyone ever want to use fsck's "interactive mode"?

Comment: As someone who has written Ext3 code, I can tell from experience that a common cause of disk corruption is experts meddling with disk structures. At least these people benefit ;)

Comment: @MSalters:  Why shouldn't those experts use one of `fsck`'s automatic modes instead of "interactive mode"?

Comment: Because those experts generally do have an idea what they did wrong, and how it should be fixed - better than fsck does.

Comment: @MSalters: And why would experts ever meddle with disk structures in the first place?

Comment: Well, if we didn't, we'd all still use Ext2. Innovation isn't magic, going from Ext2 to Ext3 took more than a decision to increment the number. E.g. you'd want to know what damage an old tool will do, if it expects Ext2 and gets Ext3.